# Clone and advertise exist eddystone beacone

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, clone

i have problem with clone and advertise exists eddystone beacone. I tried nrf connect app to clone and advertise beacone its working but only for iphone device android cant check my location us "i am in store".So someone please can help me with this.I want this to use like i am in store but i will at my house.